# Chapter Skip Buttons Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, animation

I am pretty new to JavaScript and I am making a Fractured Fairytale animation on Edge Animate, but I am having trouble creating a chapter skip button which finds the current position on the timeline and goes to the next closest label.

I have multiple labels in my animation for each scene. E.g Scene 1, Scene 2, etc.

So far I have come up with this but it doesn't seem to work past the first scene and comes up as an error code on Edge Animate.

```
var pos = sym.getPosition() 

if (pos => '0'){
  sym.play('Scene 1');
}
else if (pos => '2000'){
  sym.play('Scene 2');
}
else if (pos => '6000'){
  sym.play('Scene 3');
}
else if (pos => '10000'){
  sym.play('END');
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question rather than linking to an image

Comment: Why couldn't you have just answered the question?

Comment: Because you'll get a better response if you learn to ask well formatted questions on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of checking values should be reversed otherwise `pos` will almost always be greater than 0 and just keep jumping to the first scene.  Also the `=>` needs to be `>=` in javascript.

```
var pos = sym.getPosition(); // I'm assuming this returns a number

if (pos >= 10000) {
  sym.play('END');
}
else if (pos >= 6000) {
  sym.play('Scene 3');
}
else if (pos >= 2000) {
  sym.play('Scene 2');
}
else {
  sym.play('Scene 1');
}
```